# SecretKeyFactory generateSecret error when passing PBEKeySpec

Tags: java, android, aes

I'm currently trying to encrypt and decrypt java String. For this purpose I wrote the 2 methods below :

```
public static String AESencryptString(String clearStr) throws Exception {
    String cipherStr = null;

    //génération de la clé de cryptage AES
    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(KEY.toCharArray());
    Log.d("test", ""+ spec);
    SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
    SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");

    //cryptage du mot de passe
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] cipherByteArray = cipher.doFinal(clearStr.getBytes("UTF-8"));

    //convertion du mot de passe en String pour l'enregistrement en base
    cipherStr = new String(Base64.encode(cipherByteArray, 0));

    return cipherStr;
}

public static String AESdecryptString(String cipherStr) throws Exception {
    String clearStr = null;

    //génération de la clé de cryptage AES
    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(KEY.toCharArray());
    SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
    SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");

    //décryptage du mot de passe
    Cipher decipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    decipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] clearByteArray = decipher.doFinal(cipherStr.getBytes());

    //convertion du mot de passe en String pour l'enregistrement en base
    clearStr = new String(Base64.encode(clearByteArray, 0));

    return clearStr;
}
```

The thrown error is "InvalidKeySpec" during the execution of factory.generateSecret -> I know that this error is due to the lack of SALT but, if I can create a PBEKeySpec with just a password, it should have a way to use it, can you help to find it ?

I tried with the SALT, just for testing and... It doesn't work either but the error is not the same. In this case the error is thrown on "cipher.init" and I can't figure out what is this error because the debugger tells me ""

Please help me because I'll going crazy !

Answer (score 1):

When creating the [PBEKeySpec](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/spec/PBEKeySpec.html) you have to use the constructor with four arguments:

```
PBEKeySpec(char[] password, byte[] salt, int iterationCount, int keyLength)
```

Note: You can store the unencrypted salt right before the encrypted text. The iterationCount can be hard-coded within your application.

```
byte[] salt = new byte[8];
new SecureRandom().nextBytes(salt);
PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(KEY.toCharArray(), salt, 10000, 128);
```

The example uses 128 for AES128 which is usually sufficient.

Comment: Thank you !  But I have an other question : if I can't use  the constructor with one argument in this situation,  on which case can I use it?

Comment: That depends on the used SecretKeyfactory. PBEKeySpec is part of the general Java Crypto API. You can implement an SecretKeyFactory that can work with an PBEKeySpec only containing a password. But in your case using the ScretKeyfactory "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1" for generating an AES key requires all 4 parameters.

Comment: Is there a way to create an AES key with another secretKeyFactory that accept the one argument PBEKeySpec?

Comment: @neobagram Please ask different questions as (guess what) different questions. Answering a question does not mean that the person that gave the answer has to provide consultancy.

Comment: @neobagram: Why? Please read about PNKDF2 what it does and why it does what it does. If you have understood it you will not ask this question.

Comment: Yes sure, but as you can read I understand what is the problem and even if I read the sun article about PBKDF2 I still don't understand why

Comment: I am not talking about a programming article how to use PBKDF2 I am talking about the security principles and possible attacks.